# replace column with other column if value is ABC*

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

MYSQL PHPmyAdmin

I have a table "photo"
I have a column named "column_title" (varchar(300)) and a column named "column_description" (text).

The title is sometimes ABC and a number. Sometimes ABC and more letters.
**ABC**1, **ABC**2, **ABC**9999, ... **ABC**DEFG745G

i want to replace each "column_title" with "column_description"
if the value is starting with "ABC" (and a number after).

```
UPDATE photos
SET variable = 'column_title', variable = 'column_description'
WHERE column_title = ABC%;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need `LIKE` operator :

```
UPDATE photos
  SET column_title = column_description 
WHERE column_title LIKE 'ABC%';
```

Comment: thank you so much. manualy 4 hours, mysql 3 seconds. Thank you.